# Installing drivers for Canon TS5160 printer/scanner on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

Can I get some help with installing drivers for Canon TS5160 printer/scanner on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. I am a Ubuntu novice.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS was released in 2018-April (thus 18.04 given the *year.month* release format used by Ubuntu) with 5 years of supported life, ie. until 2023-April. Why would you wish to spend time on a release that's about to go EOSS (*end of standard support*, why not plan your *release-upgrade* to move to a *supported* release that has more than mere days left of it's *standard* support.

Comment: Thanks for that info. Where/how do I get the latest version ?

Comment: You didn't say what Ubuntu product you're using (only the release was 18.04, not Server, Desktop etc), but you can start with https://ubuntu.com/download and scroll down the page to select the product/architecture etc. you're after.  Extra FYI:  The LTS or *long-term-support* releases are the first release in the *even* year, so maybe where to start, ie. 18.04, 20.04, 22.04 - 22.04 or 2022-April release the current *latest* LTS release; 23.04 the newest release that isn't a LTS (9 months only of support for non-LTS)

Comment: Thanks again. I have a laptop. Can I download that with Firefox on the internet ?

Comment: Yep.  click the *Download Ubuntu Desktop* option (Desktop means is the version of Ubuntu with Desktop (ie. GUI or *graphical user interface*) for users, as distinct for Server which means it'll be used with terminal only (*text user interface* only, or *headless* being no-screen at all). Desktop is what you want on a laptop for normal usage.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated.

Comment: Success - the "sudo apt upgrade" is going - 22.04

Comment: After that ends, I'll be back to my question - "Can I get some help with installing drivers for Canon TS5160 printer/scanner on Ubuntu (22.04 hopefully)"

Comment: All finished - I will now reboot and see what I have ! Thanks.

Comment: No joy with that - I now have 18.04.6 CTS, up from 18.04.2 CTS

Comment: `sudo apt upgrade` will only upgrade packages on your existing release; and won't upgrade all anyway (`sudo apt full-upgrade` will install all upgrades), but neither is the command to upgrade your system to 20.04 (`do-release-upgrade` can do that for example).

Comment: Thanks again. Does that mean 'do-release-upgrade' will upgrade my 18.04 to 22.04 ? I am running Ubuntu off a Xtra-PC memory stick.

Comment: No; Ubuntu releases will only upgrade to (a) the next release (18.04 to 18.10; but that isn't possible since 18.10 is EOL) or (b) to the next LTS (18.04 to 20.04). You can read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FocalUpgrades for some pointers (20.04 release announcements & notes had links to it). It'll apply if an installed system, but I'd not expect it to work if your system is using *live* with persistence (*you re-create the memory stick in that case normally*)

Comment: Thanks mate, I will try that, I have a lot to learn about Ubuntu.